# If I scaffold login.cshtml I get "This site can't be reached" error as if it can't find the path of the newly created template

Tags: asp.net-core

Using ASP.net core 6. Login works out of the box with Identity, but as soon as I scaffold it, and not even modify the code then I get a login error

Pages are in the correct default folder and nav links are pointing to them

```
This site can’t be reached The webpage at 
https://localhost:7117/Identity/Account/Login?
```

ReturnUrl=%2FIdentity%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FIdentity%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FIdentity%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FIdentity%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FIdentity%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FIdentity%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FIdentity%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252525252F
Login might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a
new web address.
ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

The only way I can resolve it is revert the commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Url indicates it was keeping `Login-AuthorizeFailed-ReturnToLoginPage-AuthorizeFailed`

I tried as you mentioned and scaffold Identity in my .net 6 project,it works well,but when I add [Authorize] Attribute on LoginModel(Pagemodel) class,it performed as you mentioned,Have you configured Authorize somewhere else ?

Result：

[image]

You could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) related or try add[AllowAnonymous] Attribute on LoginModel

Could you share in which web app you  scaffold Identity?(MVC,RazorPage,Blazor?),and it would help if you could upload the minimal codes that could reproduce your error.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It gave me the idea on how to solve it In my program.cs is options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder() which specified authorization. commenting it out fixed it.!

Comment: Fix 2. As the fallbackpolicy is to have everything authorised, then to access the login  page you have to be logged in! Adding  [AllowAnonymous] to the login page fixes that but then it doesnt process the login